# how to use positioning/range in regexp

Tags: sql, regex, google-bigquery

I have a product code where the references always follows this pattern: `XX00XX000XX`. Characters 1 and 2 are always a combination of 2 letters, 3 to 4 a combination of 2 numbers, 5 to 6 letters, 7 to 10 numbers and 10 to 11 letters again (they`re always varying so it'll never be the same).

I want to do a regexp_contains (or another variant) that matches by position like; position 1 - 2 must be [[:alpha:]], 3 - 4 [[:digit:]], and so on.

(I need this to find product codes that match the reference pattern inside sell links, but I can't find any clear explanation on how to use positioning on regex statements...)

Answer (score 0):

You can use character classes for this.

```
[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]\d\d[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]\d\d\d[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]
```

This regex contains the class `[a-zA-Z]` and `\d`, which matches `letter` and `digit` respectively. This explicitly checks, first character is a letter, second character is a letter, third character is a digit, etc.

The character classes match 1 character in the set specified, so `[a-zA-Z]` matches any letter, `[13579]` will match any odd number, etc.

Comment: i tried REGEXP_CONTAINS(Ref, r'[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]\d\d[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]\d\d\d[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]')and didnt work in bigquery